# Why setInterval function cannot stop setTimeOut from running?

Tags: javascript, console, settimeout, setinterval, infinite-loop

I was learning Javscript and tried this piece of code:

```
var a=true;
let c=0;
setTimeout(()=>{
console.log("a is false");
},2000);

setInterval(()=>{
console.log(c++);
},200)
```

I was thinking that this code produces an infinite loop upon execution however it didn't.

As JS is a single threaded language, we have the setInterval running at every 200ms so it stays in the main thread.After 2 seconds setTimeout should execute but as setInterval is running at that instant , the main thread should be occupied with setInterval.But still the setTimeout function is executed which I cant understand..

Comment: `so it stays in the main thread` no it doesn't - `JS is a single threaded language` - but the engine running your js code isn't

Answer (score 1):

Single threaded doesn't mean that you only have one execution context. JS is event-driven, and, although not multi-threaded, there is an orchestrator (called the event loop), which ensures that functions call happen when they should.

In your case, the setInterval is scheduled to run every 200ms, and that is not blocking any other code from running if it has been scheduled (such as your setTimeout).

Both pieces of code run in the same thread here, and are properly scheduled by the event loop.

Also: you DO have an infinite loop. The `setInterval` function will never stop.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that this is the code:

```
var a=true&&false;
let c=0+1;
setTimeout(function1,1000);
setInterval(function2, 200);
```

**CallStack** is the stack where the JS is executed

**Callback queue** is the queue where async code queues up when it is ready for execution

Between the call stack and callback queue is the very famous **event loop**; It is something that constantly monitors the queue and passes the thing in the top of the queue to the stack if execution call stack is empty

| Time | Code Executed |
| --- | --- |
| 1ms | "var a=true&&false;" is moved to CallStack and Immmediately executed |
| 2ms | "let c=0+1;" is moved to CallStack and Immmediately executed |
| 3ms | "setTimeout(function1,1000);" is moved to CallStack and Immmediately executed; But here, the execution is handing over function1 to WebAPI setTimeout; The setTimeout API starts a timer of 2000ms at this point |
| 4ms | "setInterval(function2, 200);" is moved to CallStack and Immmediately executed; But here, the execution is handing over function2 to WebAPI setInterval; The setInterval API starts a timer of 200ms at this point |
| 5ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |
| 204ms | setInterval adds function2 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function2 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log(c++); of function2 gets executed |
| 205ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |
| 404ms | setInterval adds function2 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function2 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log(c++); of function2 gets executed |
| 405ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |
| 604ms | setInterval adds function2 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function2 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log(c++); of function2 gets executed |
| 605ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |
| 804ms | setInterval adds function2 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function2 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log(c++); of function2 gets executed |
| 805ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |
| 1003ms | setTimeout adds function1 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function1 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log("a is false"); of function1 gets executed |
| 1004ms | setInterval adds function2 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function2 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log(c++); of function2 gets executed |
| 1005ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |
| 1204ms | setInterval adds function2 to callback queue; The Event loop finds function2 in the callback queue and immediately gives it to the callStack for execution; console.log(c++); of function2 gets executed |
| 1205ms | No Code in CallStack and Eventloop does not find anything in the callback queue; So, nothing to execute |
| ... | ... |

Pay attention to what happens at 1003, 1004 and 1005 ms.
This is how it will work. The key thing is non blocking I/0. Out I/0 in this case is the webApi setTimeout and setInterval

P.S - I have added expressions in the code line 1 and 2 because declarations ideally do not take execution time. In reality, the expression executions take far less than 1ms in modern OS. This was done for simplification purpose only.